# Animation on back key pressed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, animation

I want to add an out animation when the back key is pressed, before it actually goes back. Right now I just have the animation playing inside of the override method for the back key. It doesn't play the animation fully though. Is there a way to cancel the back event and add it to the animation completion event? Or what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress( System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e )
{
  if( NavigationService.CanGoBack() ) {
    // Cancel the navigation
    e.Cancel = true;

    //Create the storyboard
    Storyboard anim = new MyCoolAnimation();

    // Hook an on complete handler
    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = ( s, e ) => {
      // Navigate backward
      NavigationService.GoBack();

      anim.Completed -= handler;
    };
    anim.Completed += handler;

    // Start the storyboard
    anim.Begin();
  }
}
```

Comment: will this also work to close the last page of an app and therefore close it?

Comment: @Matt Lacey: I don't think so; I think `NavigationService.CanGoBack()` returns `false` for the last page (first page when app is started)